# How do I define an equation in Windows 10 Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to update a spreadsheet that was created years ago by a person who no longer works for this office.

Some of the functionality is not working and I am trying to decipher what is broken and how to fix it.

These are just a couple of the equations that are effected:

```
="  "&MID(Dates!$A$13,(MONTH(Dates!$A$11)*10+1),3)&" "&FIXED(DAY(Dates!$A$11),0)&", "&YEAR(Dates!$A$11)
```

and:

```
=Annual!P39
```

How do I find what cell is named Annual?

Comment: That's a cross-sheet reference.  A cell address has three parts: sheet, row, column.  If you omit the sheet and just give row and column, Excel looks up that row and column on the current sheet.

Comment: What you call "equations" are commonly referred to as "formulas" in Excel. If they are "not working", you may want to detail what you expect to see and what you see instead. If there is a result, but it is wrong, you need to give us more than the formula. If there is an error message, then share that. Please update your question to add those details. Again. Please update the question.

Comment: Annual might be a worksheet like Dates in the above formula